# Can session variables be used to separate landing pages geographically?

Tags: php, html, session

This is probably a dumb question.  I have a Web site that uses php and html with a bit of Javascript.  I am trying to set it up so there are multiple landing pages.  I think it would work if all the remaining .php files on the site were kept identical but there were separate index_a.php, index_b.php files, etc.  The only problem is when the user clicks "Home" they of course get the root index.php.  Is there a way to store the name (or some other indication) of what the user's landing page was for that session (using PHP session variables or I don't know what) and have the user directed to that page again when they click Home ?

Any help would be much appreciated (keeping in my mind I am a relative newby and any solution would need to be pretty simple and safe to load on a server).  Any straightforward way way to do this ?  It must be something that is fairly commonly required.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question but the short answer is 'yes', you can store data about the user's landing page in a session variable for use later..

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes

Smart answer: use a (mvc) [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP) of some kind which implements views and routes everything through a front controller.

Quick and dirty answer:

```
// anywhere
session_start();
$_SESSION['landing_page'] = 'landing-2.html';

// in your index.php
session_start();
include $_SESSION['landing_page'];
```

Note: if you use the code above, be sure the torn of the security gods will fall upon you.